# SAP GUI How to find number of rows when creating a BOM for use in VBA

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I'm trying to write a function to copy BOMs (SAP ERP) from an old part to a new part, only changing material quantity.  To do this I need to know how many rows of materials are in each particular BOM, which changes depending on the part.  When I use the script recorder in SAP GUI, it seems to refer to each row *relative to the top of the screen*.  First row is 0, second is 1, and so on.  If I scroll down, there's a new 0 row.  Is there an easier way to find how many rows have data in them?

Example row 0:

```
wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS_ITOV/tabpTCMA/ssubSUBPAGE:SAPLCSDI:0152/tblSAPLCSDITCMAT/txtRC29P-MENGE[4,0]
```

[image: example of such a BOM]

There are additional rows if you were to keep scrolling.

Comment: It's hard to fully understand your question. Write a function in ABAP? In VBA? Can you show what have you tried? Can you give more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SAPsession.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS_ITOV/tabpTCMA/ssubSUBPAGE:SAPLCSDI:0152/tblSAPLCSDITCMAT").rowcount
```

will give you the number of rows on the subpage. You then just need to loop through them.

In VBA, something like:

```
    allrows  = SAPsession.findById  ("wnd0]/usr/tabsTS_ITOV/tabpTCMA/ssubSUBPAGE:SAPLCSDI:0152/tblSAPLCSDITCMAT").rowcount

For row = 0 to allrows
  product = session.findById("wnd0]/usr/tabsTS_ITOV/tabpTCMA/ssubSUBPAGE:SAPLCSDI:0152/tblSAPLCSDITCMAT/ctxtRC29P-IDNRK[4," & row & "]").Text
next row
```